# Text selection for date range not working with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, daterangepicker

I am using Bootstrap3. I have a button that opens a modal and date range selection input box within it. When I click the input box date range calendar opens up. I can select the date range but I could not change the date. It seems like z-index problem of modal and it somehow doesn't allow to select date in text field.

I have tried without the modal and it works fine.

I need to show a modal box and display a date-range calendar with date text modification.

Comment: Please provide code of what you've tryied

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".modal-body", function () {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'                                    
     });
      });  
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some commentary to as why your soluton works. Code only answers are poor answers. Thanks!

Comment: Explaining your answer enlighten us.

Comment: @AJT_82 Its not possible to all the time to explain every thing, i don't want to waste reader's time. that is the reason i am not adding comments. simply i added code i feels which is suitable for  this case.

Comment: thank you @αƞjiβ you also doing great job. its very useful to us, keep it up

Comment: Very often code only answers are marked as low quality answers, and sent to review, where community decides if the answer should be deleted. So there is that possibility, therefore I just wanted to give you a tip to elaborate on your answer before this happens: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal has z-index 1040. So give your calendar a z-index greater than 1040.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried with.

```
    function zIndexModifier() {
        $("#modal_dialog").css("display", "none");
        $(".daterangepicker").css("z-index", 100000);

    }
```

it works when

```
$("#modal_dialog").css("display", "none");
```

but the calender jumps over top.

Is there any solution to this so that i can keep modal as well as calender with date-text selection.